# Is there a good, non-Google Reader RSS reader for iPhone/iPod?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, rss

I'm looking for an app to read RSS feeds on my iPod Touch. I saw Reeder, but it looks like it only interoperates with Google Reader, as far as I can tell -- you can't just add an arbitrary RSS feed. Is there a good RSS reader that works without Google Reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NewsRack](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/newsrack/id288815275?mt=8) is pretty solid, with a simple clean interface, and the ability to add feeds directly int he app- no Google reader required.

I use Reeder now, which I think has a nicer, slicker interface, but Reeder requires Google sync - you can't add feeds directly in the app.   Before that, I was very happy with NewsRack.

[image]

Comment: Does NewsRack allow offline reading?

Answer (score 1):

NetNewsWire is a good reader and syncing with Google Reader is optional.